# How to make function NOT highlight last row in table?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a function that highlights each row in a table 
(css code)

```
.stripe1 {
    background-color:#999999;
}
.stripe2 {
    background-color:#666666;
}
.highlight {
    background-color: #ffcc66;
    font-weight:bold;
}


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#table-example-1 tr:even").addClass("stripe1");
        $("#table-example-1 tr:odd").addClass("stripe2");

        $("#table-example-1 tr").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
            },
            function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

It works great only the last line in the table the tfoot
I would like it to be a different color(red).

How would I be able to accomplish this ?
I made a http://jsfiddle.net/pd981Lps/ , change my code a little bit to make think easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your selectors to target `tbody`: `$("#table-example-1 tbody tr")`

Comment: thanks, i guess after codeing for many hours in a day cant think straight